# How do I calculate Oxygen requirement in an aerobic waste water pond?

Tags: water

Assuming I have data of BOD, COD and water discharge. How do I calculate the O2 requirement?

Comment: This is an ambiguous question. The COD chews up the matter using very strong oxidizers so that oxygen demand will in general be greater than the BOD. However it depends on what is being consumed. For example for table sugar the BOD and COD will be the same. But the COD will decompose polyethylene which the BOD won't touch.

Comment: For the future, it would be great if someone edited in what COD/BOD are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can actually calculate the theoretical oxygen requirement using the following formula:
O2 req (kgO2/d) = [Q * (S0-S) / (BOD5/BODL)]/ 1000
Where:
Q= flowrate m3/day
S0= infulent BOD/COD concentration (mg/L)
S= efulent BOD/COD concentration (mg/L)

FYI Successful decreasing of BOD and COD can be obtain by using high volume Oxygen Generator such as [Submersible Aeration](http://www.isw.co.id/turbo-pro-aerator-eng)